# How to run queries on multiple linked servers efficiently?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, linked-server

I have to run several queries on a set of linked servers.  I want to try and do it without resorting to dynamic sql, but having trouble so far.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT @serverName = Name FROM #servers WHERE ID = @minID

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server=@serverName, @srvproduct='SQL Server'         
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'lani-radio001', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False', @rmtuser = N'user1', @rmtpassword = N'Password1'

declare @sql varchar(255)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * from [' + @serverName + '].mydb.dbo.mytable'
EXEC (@sql)
```

I have to run the above code in a loop against multiple servers (which are all in #servers table).
How can I pull this off without resorting to dynamic SQL?

P.S. All servers in question are SQL Server 2005.

Comment: not sure you can without dynamic sql. The only other possible answer would be to use powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(@serverName,'select * from mydb.dbo.mytable');
```